# ValueError while running Python script from command line

Tags: python, arrays, string, command-line, integer

I am trying to call a python script from the command line as follows:

python Browse_list.py "firefox" "https://www.n11.com/magaza/tozbitti?iw=motor"["&m=Aeg","&m=Arnica","&m=Bosch","&m=Electrolux","&m=Philips"] [1,1,1,1,1] [4,2,7,4,6] "&pg="

Here is the script file:

```
import sys
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
import os

if sys.argv[1] == 'Chrome':

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.getcwd() + '\\chromedriver.exe')

elif sys.argv[1] == 'Firefox':

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=os.getcwd() + '\\geckodriver.exe')

elif sys.argv[1] == 'Microsoft Edge':

    driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path=os.getcwd() + '\\msedgedriver.exe')

elif sys.argv[1] == 'Opera':

    driver = webdriver.Opera(executable_path=os.getcwd() + '\\operadriver.exe')

n = len(sys.argv[3])
s = sys.argv[3][1:n-1] 
s = s.split(',') 

a = sys.argv[4][1:n-1] 
a = a.split(',') 
  
A = [int(i) for i in a]

b = sys.argv[5][1:n-1] 
b = b.split(',') 
  
B = [int(i) for i in b]

for j in range(0, len(A)): 

    for i in range(A[j], B[j]):

        driver.get(sys.argv[2]+s[j]+sys.argv[6]+str(i))

        sleep(4)

#driver.quit()
```

I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "Browse_list.py", line 30, in <module>
        A = [int(i) for i in a]
      File "Browse_list.py", line 30, in <listcomp>
        A = [int(i) for i in a]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,1,1,1,1]'
```

how to resolve and change the array of strings to array of ints? Thanks.

Comment: You error message clearly says that you are trying to conver ‘1,1,1,1,1]’ into int... add print after a.split(‘,’) and you will see what you are giving loop and a

Comment: I did and resolved the error, thanks.

Comment: In Python, we called them `lists`, not `arrays`.
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp
:)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not parsing data type because command line arguments are always passed as strings. You will need to parse them into your required data type

#### not correct

```py
a = a.split(',') 
b = b.split(',')
```

#### correct

```py
a = map(int, a.strip('[]').split(','))
b = map(int, b.strip('[]').split(','))
```

so your final code looks like :

```
import sys
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
import os
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

if sys.argv[1] == 'Chrome':

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.getcwd() + '\\chromedriver.exe')

elif sys.argv[1] == 'Firefox':

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=os.getcwd() + '\\geckodriver.exe')

elif sys.argv[1] == 'Microsoft Edge':

    driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path=os.getcwd() + '\\msedgedriver.exe')

elif sys.argv[1] == 'Opera':

    driver = webdriver.Opera(executable_path=os.getcwd() + '\\operadriver.exe')

n = len(sys.argv[3])
s = sys.argv[3][1:n-1] 
s = s.split(',') 

a = sys.argv[4][1:n-1] 
a = map(int, a.strip('[]').split(','))
  
A = [int(i) for i in a]

b = sys.argv[5][1:n-1] 
b = map(int, b.strip('[]').split(','))
  
B = [int(i) for i in b]
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
for j in range(0, len(A)): 

    for i in range(A[j], B[j]):

        
        driver.get(sys.argv[2]+s[j]+sys.argv[6]+str(i))

        sleep(4)

#driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though all arrays are of the same size I had to get the length of each array separately as in following:

```
n = len(sys.argv[3])
s = sys.argv[3][1:n-1] 
s = s.split(',') 

n = len(sys.argv[4])
a = sys.argv[4][1:n-1]
a = a.split(',') 
  
A = [int(i) for i in a]

n = len(sys.argv[5])
b = sys.argv[5][1:n-1] 
b = b.split(',')
```

Maybe it differs how python gets each input which makes the length different so you to get the length each time.